# Boolean with swift

Tags: ios, swift

This is really confusing. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
let viewHasMovedToRight == false //initially I want this to be false
```

then

```
func moveViewToRight(sender: UIButton!) {
        if viewHasMovedToRight == false {               
            viewHasMovedToRight == true;

            UIView.animateWithDuration(
                0.75,
                animations: {},
                completion: { (value: Bool) in
                     println(" moved")                     
                }
            )
        }                
        else {                
            viewHasMovedToRight == false;             
            UIView.animateWithDuration(
                0.75,
                animations:{},
                completion:{ (value: Bool) in                     
                    println("not moved")                       
                }
            )
        }

       // println("move view")
    }
```

Only the first `if` is called. 
I cannot re-assign the value back to true...

Something that was so easy on Obj-C now with swift is so frustrating...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have two problems.

One, you are using `==` (which tests for equality) where you should be using `=` (which assigns a value).  Two, you are declaring a constant and then trying to assign a new value to it later.  You need to declare a variable.

```
var viewHasMovedToRight = false

...
    viewHasMovedToRight = true
```

Also, most people would find this `if` condition more understandable:

```
if !viewHasMovedToRight {
```

And it would be even simpler if you were to reverse the order of your `if` clauses:

```
if viewHasMovedToRight {
    viewHasMovedToRight = false
    ...
} else {
    viewHasMovedToRight = true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`let viewHasMovedToRight = false` not `let viewHasMovedToRight == false`

EDIT: It looks like you use `==` instead of `=` everywhere you are setting the boolean.

Comment: when i do that I get the error cannot assign to "" in 'self'

Comment: @GeorgeAsda Use `=` to set the `Bool`. Use `==` to test the state of the `Bool`. And use `let` if you're dealing with constant, but use `var` if it's a variable whose value can change (which is clearly the case).

Answer (score 3):

@George,
you should use set operator

```
let viewHasMovedToRight = false
```

not comparison operator

```
let viewHasMovedToRight == false
```

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here.
I used to do that mistake all the time, using = both for assign and to compare.
Use = to assign and == to compare