# I created a Custom UIView in which I am trying to use a UISwitch to toggle a blackStroke border on and off

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2

However, it doesn't seem to be working as anticipated. The `UISwitch` in swift does not do it's job when paired with the custom UI. It does not toggle on and off the border (or stroke border). I have this condition created in custom `UIView`

```
var hasBlackBorder:Bool = false

if (hasBlackBorder == true) { //NOT WORKING
    myPath.lineWidth = CGFloat(3)
    let strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    strokeColor.setStroke()

    myPath.stroke() //for black border only
    myPath.closePath()
} else {
    myPath.lineWidth = CGFloat(0)
    let strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    strokeColor.setStroke()
    myPath.stroke()
    myPath.closePath()
}
```

In my `ViewController`, I attempt to work some magic and I create a conditional statement to toggle on and off the border like so:

```
@IBAction func withnwithoutBorder(sender: UISwitch) {
    if (hasBorder.on) { //Call does not seem to be working? Any suggestions?
        thePolygon.hasBlackBorder == true
        thePolygon.setNeedsDisplay()
    } else {
        thePolygon.hasBlackBorder == false
        thePolygon.setNeedsDisplay()
    }   
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boolean with swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514204/boolean-with-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode should already be giving you a warning on this line:

```
    thePolygon.hasBlackBorder == true
```

The warning is “Result of call to '==' is unused”. This is because `==` is an operator that tests for equality. It is not the assignment operator.

You want to do this instead:

```
    thePolygon.hasBlackBorder = true
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, thanks. I can't believe i made such a novice error.

Comment: Hey, you're the one who put “n00b” in your username… ;^)